# Олимпиадная задача. Монетки

Tags: c++, олимпиада, числа-фибоначчи

Ограничение времени 1 секунда

Ограничение памяти  512Mb

**Условие:**

Как всем хорошо известно, дядюшка Скрудж очень богат. Все свое свободное время он проводит со своими золотыми монетам. Сегодня он решил сложить их в столбики, используя следующий алгоритм: первый столбик имеет высоту А, а второй - В. Высота каждого нового столбца должна равняться сумме высот двух последних построенных. Если высота столбика превышает С, то он убирает из нее С монет.

Определите, какой высоты будет К-ый столбик.

Формат ввода
Заданы четыре целых числа A, B, C, K

(0 ≤ A, B ≤ 1000000000; 1 ≤ C, K ≤ 1000000000; A < C; B < C).

Формат вывода
Выведите одно число - количество монет в K-ом столбике.

**Пример 1**

*Ввод*

1 1 10 2

*Вывод*

1

**Пример 2**

*Ввод:*

2 5 13 5

*Вывод*:

6

**Моя попытка решения:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long a, b, c, k, n, l1, l2;

int main() {
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> k;

    if (k == 1) {
        cout << a;
    }
    else if (k == 2) {
        cout << b;
    }
    else {
        l1 = a;
        l2 = b;
        for (long long i = 3; i <= k; i++) {
            n = l1 + l2;
            if (n > c)
                n -= c;
            l1 = l2;
            l2 = n;
        }

        cout << n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Хотел просто перебрать, но не проходит по времени на 6 тестах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Так а где Вы читаете в цикле ввод?

Comment: Если бы вы давали URL проверяющей системы, отвечать было бы проще :)

Comment: @Harry, https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/15927/problems/C/

Comment: @EOF, извините, я не ту задачу добавил (

Comment: Вобщем, куда-то сюда думать надо - https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/commit/0df59e0877b1e21b1ecd76b2cf4af09a6a362522#262fb663f2c73fcd6d6974813c932433258b7afd - но что-то по позднему времени голова не варит, где я ошибаюсь. 7 тестов проходит, потом :( Смысл - считать Фибоначчи быстрым возведением в степень.

Comment: `F(1) = A`, `F(2) = B`, `F(n) = Fib(n-1) * B + Fib(n-2) * A`, задача вывести `F(K) mod C`. `Fib(n)` - n-ное число Фибоначчи, оно может считаться через возведение матрицы в степень за `O(log(n))`. Конкретный алгоритм можно нагуглить.

Comment: Ага, забыл о случае нулевых первых столбцов - что значит смотреть на задачу утром...

Comment: Теоретически, вероятно, что замены `n-=c` на `n%=c` было бы достаточно)

Comment: @vp_arth нет, не было бы. Если немного посчитать, то видно, что для любого значения f оно меньше 2c, так что достаточно и вычитания, а остаток от деления - это более дорогостоящая операция, чем вычитание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> fib(unsigned long long N,
                                                 unsigned long long A,
                                                 unsigned long long B,
                                                 unsigned long long C)
{
    unsigned long long a[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    unsigned long long r[2][2] = {{1,0},{0,1}};
    while(N)
    {
        unsigned long long b[2][2];
        if (N&1) {
            b[0][0] = a[0][0]*r[0][0] + a[0][1]*r[1][0];
            b[0][1] = a[0][0]*r[0][1] + a[0][1]*r[1][1];
            b[1][0] = a[1][0]*r[0][0] + a[1][1]*r[1][0];
            b[1][1] = a[1][0]*r[0][1] + a[1][1]*r[1][1];
            r[0][0] = b[0][0]%C;
            r[0][1] = b[0][1]%C;
            r[1][0] = b[1][0]%C;
            r[1][1] = b[1][1]%C;
        }
        N >>= 1;
        b[0][0] = a[0][0]*a[0][0] + a[0][1]*a[1][0];
        b[0][1] = a[0][0]*a[0][1] + a[0][1]*a[1][1];
        b[1][0] = a[1][0]*a[0][0] + a[1][1]*a[1][0];
        b[1][1] = a[1][0]*a[0][1] + a[1][1]*a[1][1];
        a[0][0] = b[0][0]%C;
        a[0][1] = b[0][1]%C;
        a[1][0] = b[1][0]%C;
        a[1][1] = b[1][1]%C;
    }
    return make_pair(r[0][0]*B + r[0][1]*A,r[1][0]*B+r[1][1]*A);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long A, B, C, K;
    cin >> A >> B >> C >> K;
    if (K == 1) cout << A << "\n";
    else if (K == 2) cout << B << "\n";
    else if (A == 0 && B == 0) cout << B << "\n";
    else
    {
        auto p = fib(K-2,A,B,C);
        A = p.first%C;
        if (A == 0) A = C;
        cout << A << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Утро начинается не с кофе)

Comment: @EOF Увы, да - оно начинается с измерения давления... :(

Comment: @Harry, огромное Вам спасибо!